# Create custom pop up test over image in phonegap?

Tags: javascript, html, css, jquery-mobile, cordova

I am trying to pop up a test message on particular pin, but not able to do.
`I've Four different Pin named Red, Blue, Green and Yellow.`
When i click on Yellow Pin Point in below image

[image]

I get the Following pop up message in Below Image

[image]

But, **I want to Display the pop up in below given Image Style**.

[image]

**I have tried the given below Code**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/pin.css" />
</head>
<script>
function myfunction()
{
    var div = document.createElement('div');
    div.className += 'popup';
    div.innerHTML = 'This is a Tool Tip Pop UP';
    document.body.appendChild(div);
}
</script>
<body>
  <h2>India Map</h2>
  <img border="0" src="img/indiaMap.png" alt="Pulpit rock" width="308" height="475">

    <div class ="pinArea">
        <img src="img/blue.png" id="redpin" onclick="alert('Hi, I am Blue');"/>
    </div>

    <div class ="pinArea" style=" top:64px;left:83px; position:absolute;" onclick="myfunction()">
        <img src="img/yellow.png" id="redpin" onclick="alert('Hi, I am Blue);"/>
    </div>

    <div class ="pinArea" style=" top:90px;left:90px; position:absolute;">
        <img src="img/red.png" id="redpin" onclick="alert('Hi, I am Blue);"/>
    </div>

    <div class ="pinArea" style=" top:90px;left:120px; position:absolute;">
        <img src="img/green.png" id="redpin" onclick="alert('Hi, I am Blue);"/>
    </div>

    <div class ="pinArea" style="top:200px;">
        <img src="img/blue.png" id="redpin" onclick="alert('Hi, I am Blue);"/>
    </div>

    <div class ="pinArea" style="top:220px; left 120px; position:absolute;">
        <img src="img/red.png" id="redpin" onclick="alert('Hi, I am Blue);"/>
    </div>

    <div class ="pinArea" style="top:230px; left:83px; position:absolute;">
        <img src="img/green.png" id="redpin" onclick="alert('Hi, I am Blue);"/>
    </div>

    <div class ="pinArea" style="top:240px; left:90px; position:absolute;">
        <img src="img/yellow.png" id="redpin" onclick="alert('Hi, I am Blue);"/>
    </div>

    <div class ="pinArea" style="top:300px;">
        <img src="img/blue.png" id="redpin" onclick="alert('Hi, I am Blue);"/>
    </div>

    <div class ="pinArea" style="top:400px; right:">
       <img src="img/blue.png" id="redpin" onclick="alert('Hi, I am Blue);"/>
    </div>

    <div class ="pinArea" style="top:500px;">
        <img src="img/blue.png" id="redpin" onclick="alert('Hi, I am Blue);"/>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Refer- https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox.js/example/v1.0.0/custom-popup/

Comment: @Suhas thanks for answering, could u please tell me how can i add map.js code with my code.

Comment: @Suhas i am using only images

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the following style to your pop up
Your HTML:

```
<div class="popup" style="background: red; border-color: red;">University</div>
```

Your CSS:

```
.popup {
margin: 10px;
padding: 25px;
position: relative;
width:50px;

}
.popup:after {
content: "";
position: absolute;
top: 100%;
left: 20px;
border-top: 20px solid blue;
border-top-color: inherit; 
border-left: 20px solid transparent;
border-right: 20px solid transparent; 
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ShinyMetilda/Fz2YF/1/

position the pop up element relative to the pin position.It should give you the required styling

Try the following fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/ShinyMetilda/8y5Aj/2/

This is to close the div.You can use an "x" image instead of button to achieve the same.

similarly to show the popup again you can use

document.getElementById("popUpDiv").style.display = "block";

Its possible check the link

http://jsfiddle.net/ShinyMetilda/JTQzk/1/

Comment: Thanks for replying. I check it in jsfiddle but, how can i close the pop , please could u explain me.. thanks

Comment: thanks for update ya it does work but i have to set x image in top right corner of the pop up. is it possible

Comment: Thanks for your answer..i will accept it... but i want to know one thing more that i've four different pin and in each pin i want to display different test pop up. is it possible. In all four different pin i want different test...

Comment: Its possible.just replicate the same procedure for all your pins.as a result you wil have four div elements with different id..u can apply javascript to show hide those div in the exact same manner

Comment: can you share your code in fiddle.I'll try to help you

Comment: above same code... i am trying to pop up over yellow pin as u can see it my code and i have 4 color pin when i click on pin, that time i have to pop up a test message (with close button).. u given me button alert... please update your answer with my code... i have not added my css file apart from that everything is in my code..

Comment: please help me out to get it. i hope that u ll understand it

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/5epkB/ I dont understand completely..but i hope this is what you are looking for..click the dummy image icon to see it work..

Comment: @ShinyJos hi bro u there. I have a similar problem but i am not using images .. i m display google map and i want to display various pins on specific lat and long